# std::nothrow for non-allocation contexts

Tags: c++, c++17, std

In my perusal of questions related to `std::nothrow`, the context is always memory allocation.  Fine, that appears to be what its intended purpose is.

However, in the libraries my team and I provide, we occasionally have interface that looks like:

```c++
string name = full_path(dir, filename);
optional<string> name = full_path(dir, filename, no_throw);
```

where the first function signature would be used when an exception-throw is allowed (i.e. the file does not exist where you think it does), whereas the the latter function signature is used whenever you are in a context where exception-throwing is not desired.

I would prefer to replace our custom-defined `no_throw` tags with `std::nothrow`, but I am not sure if this is a best practice, given that `std::nothrow` was intended to be used in allocation contexts.

Clearly, there is nothing that prevents me from doing so, but I am loath to adopt obscure coding patterns.  Guidance?

Comment: Consider whether it would be clearer to just have a `full_path_noexcept` function instead of overloading with a tag. As for the question, I don't think there are rules against using `std::nothrow_t` for this. It doesn't really matter in terms of correctness, performance or usability (as far as I can tell) so it's a question of code clarity and minimizing surprise. Since clarity is for the most part subjective, this question is probably off topic for being opinion based.

Comment: Personally, it's probably not worth refactoring your code base to sub out one clearly defined and not-abused tag struct for another one with the same name just because the latter is defined by the standard.

Comment: What about `no_throw` as a template argument?

Comment: One common approach is to pass an error code by reference to the non-throwing overload.

Comment: @AndyG Yes, that's a reasonable and persuasive argument.

Comment: @FrancoisAndrieux It wasn't obvious to me that it is a clarity issue, although I can see your point.  We strive for minimal points of maintenance, and it's generally better to use something the standard library provides than to make your own...if it makes sense to do so.  In this case, a differently named function might improve the clarity.